# File Upload to Server Directory Using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload a file to the server directory from client machine. I used the following codes :

FileUpload.jsp

```
<form:form commandName="fileUpload" action="upload.action" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<form:label path="fileData">Upload a File</form:label> <br />
<form:input type="file"  path="fileData" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" >
</form:form>
```

In my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/upload.action")
public String upload(@ModelAttribute("fileUpload") FileUpload fileUpload,HttpServletResponse response,Model model)
{
    CommonsMultipartFile multipartFile = fileUpload.getFileData();
    String orginalName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    String filePath = "/my_uploads/"+orginalName;
    File destination = new File(filePath);
    String status ="success";
    try {
        multipartFile.transferTo(destination);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        status="failure";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        status="iofailure";
    }
    model.addAttribute("status", status);
    return "home";
}
```

FileUpload.java :

```
{
   private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;
   ....
}
```

`NullPointerException` is thrown at the line `String orginalName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();` .. what wrong thing i have done??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the `MultipartFile` as a parameter in your requesthandler.

```
@RequestMapping("/upload.action")
public String upload(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletResponse response,Model model)
{
    //Controller logic...
}
```

This will require you to register a new bean in your dispatcher's configuration.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Exception thrown as `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]: Specified class is an interface`

Comment: @user1849556 see updated controller, sorry about that. It should have used `@RequestParam` instead of `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: Thank you Kevin! now the Exception is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \my_uploads\xxx.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)` .. do i have to manually create `my_uploads` folder?

Comment: The directory should exist whether you manually create it or programatically create it.

Comment: I placed `my_uploads` folder in `WebContent` folder of the project.. but still it is not working!

Comment: You need to place it in the folder specified in the system property `user.dir`.  I usually just print out this environment variable then adjust:   `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` gives `D:\My_Workspace\MyProject` and i placed my `my_uploads` folder in the same directory but still it throws FileNotFoundException at `File destination = new File(filePath);`

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping("/upload.action")
public String upload(@RequestParam("fileData") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletResponse response,Model model)
{
    //Controller logic...
}
```

you should have the same name in the parameter for your request handler method  ,whatever you given in the FileUpload Pojo for multipartFile  ("fileData")  it should be in the parameter

Thanks,